# Error while testing keras_custom_model.py of ray rllib

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I'm encountering a persistent issue while working with the Tune library in Ray RLLIB with Python on a Windows system. I'm attempting to run a test script from the library titled: custom_keras_model.py

`(raylet) [2023-08-22 15:01:41,041 E 10616 15108] (raylet.exe) worker_pool.cc:544: Some workers of the worker process(18472) have not registered within the timeout. The process is dead, probably it crashed during start.`

and here is the full log error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9gJ5.png)

This error message appears related to the initialization of Ray worker processes and suggests that some workers failed to register within a timeout period, likely crashing during startup.

I am suspecting some network Issues as network problems can sometimes prevent worker processes from registering with the Ray cluster.